# URLEncoder: encoding string in android

Tags: android

I am constructing String in my android app and then pass it to URLEncoder.

```
String searchStr;
// then I get some searchStr from shared preferences
// i check it is correct
searchStr = searchStr + "/page/"+pageNumber+"";
```

Then I pass that searchStr to URL encoder:

```
try {
  String url_params = URLEncoder.encode(params[0]);
  String result = downloadURL("some url/" + url_params);
  Log.d("key", url_params); // -> php/page/10
}catch (IOException){
  Log.d("key", e.getMessage() );
}
```

So here i get IOException which shows me this message:

```
http://some url/php%2Fpage%2F10
```

If I copy paste it to browser it shows me Not found error with this message:

```
The requested url  someurl/php/page/10 was not found on this server
```

Also if I change those strange sign %2F into / in browser I am able to get the page. So how can I construct proper string with / instead of %2F sign?

Comment: Why are you encoding the URL?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters . In your case you should probably just encode the page number (if it may contain special chars) or skip encoding altogether.

Comment: @headuck, thanks it helped)

Answer (score 2):

You don't encode the entire URL, only parts of it that come from "unreliable sources".

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```